# H2O Flow does not show my .hex file in Split Frame section

Tags: h2o

I am just learning H2O Flow as per its tutorials on Youtube. But my titanic.hex file does not show up into Split Frame section of the notebook. Any help please.

Comment: Hi Athar, can you please provide a link to the tutorial you are following? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all the available frames in Flow. Click on the Data dropdown menu at the top of the page and then click on List All Frames. If you previously clicked on Split Frames and then that cell's `Create` button you will see that the two frames you just created will appear under the list of frames. Please note that when you split the frames, if you don't specify a naming convention, those frames will get a default name like `frame_0.750`.

Please also verify, before creating the Split Frames cell, that your titanic frame actually exists in your H2O Cluster - if the import wasn't successful or the titanic frame is not in the H2O Cluster it will not appear as a dataframe that you can split on within the Split Frame Cell. Again you can see what dataframes are in your cluster by using the List All Frames option.

Comment: thanks, the problem is still there. on pressing List All Frames it shows following:


Key_Frame__http___math_ucdenver_edu_RTutorial_titanic.hex

yet it does not appear into Split dropdown. I am running h2o using Rstudio.